# Regression model function (with user selected variables) on subset of data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, linear-regression

Using data from the fivethirtyeight package...

```
library(fivethirtyeight)
grads <- college_recent_grads
```

Created a subset of the grads data to include desired variables

```
data <- grads[, c("men", "major_category", "employed", 
"employed_fulltime_yearround", "p25th", 
"p75th", "total")]
```

Then, I split the `data` subset up by major category and omitted the one NA value in the data

```
majorcats <- split(data, data$major_category)
names(majorcats)
majorcats <- majorcats %>% na.omit()
```

And tried to run a regression model in a function called facts, where the user could specify x, y, and z, z being a major category (hence why I split up the `data` subset by major_category)

```
facts <- function(x, y, z){
   category <- majorcats[["z"]]
   summary(lm(y ~ x, data = category))
 }
```

Unfortunately, when I try to input variables into facts (that are part of the majorcats data set, such as

```
facts(men, p25th, Arts)
```

I get the error below:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = y ~ x, data = category, 
drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : 
  invalid type (NULL) for variable 'y'
Called from: model.frame.default(formula = y ~ x, data = category, 
drop.unused.levels = TRUE)
Browse[1]>
```

Can someone please explain what this error means, and how I might be able to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply pass the parameters as string literals and create a formula from string:

```
facts <- function(x, y, z){
   category <- majorcats[[z]]

   model <- as.formula(paste(y, "~", x))
   # ALTERNATIVE: model <- reformulate(x, response=y)
   summary(lm(model, data = category))
 }

facts("men", "p25th", "Arts")
```

Comment: This seems to work! Can you please explain why this works, particularly the assignment of `model`?

Comment: Since you are passing dynamic values into the function, you need to build the formula. Previously your formula was `y ~ x` which neither *y* or *x* is in the data, *category*. Here, you run `p25th ~ men` and both are in data. Remember the formula in `lm()` literally look for those symbols.

Comment: What if I, after creating the `data` subset with the desired variables, did this for each of them: `men <- data$men`, `major_category <- data$major_category`, and so on for all of the variables that I have listed as part of `data`? If I do that, and then run my original `facts` function, I don't seem to get an error. Can you explain the differences between those two approaches?

Comment: What was your formula, still `y ~ x` and what did you pass into function? Actual vectors or strings? Did you use the *data* argument in `lm()` or leave it blank?

Comment: well, I had not built a formula. I created data separate objects for each of the variables in `data`. After comparing the actual regression outputs from both methods, I think I can understand why my initial method did not make sense. By not having a formula, I was just running regressions from the `data` set, and not within the category of data I wanted